# Could not do Play/Pause button in Flutter/Dart... Can someone help me with that?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is the link for the code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:meditaion_app/Models/item_model.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';


class MeditaionAppScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MeditaionAppScreen({super.key});


  @override
  State<MeditaionAppScreen> createState() => _MeditaionAppScreenState();
}


class _MeditaionAppScreenState extends State<MeditaionAppScreen> {
  final List<Item> items = [
    Item(
      name: "Forest",
      audiopath: "assets/meditation_audios/forest.mp3",
      imagepath: 'assets/meditation_images/forest.jpeg',
    ),
    Item(
      name: "Night",
      audiopath: "assets/meditation_audios/night.mp3",
      imagepath: 'assets/meditation_images/night.jpeg',
    ),
    Item(
      name: "Ocean",
      audiopath: "assets/meditation_audios/ocean.mp3",
      imagepath: 'assets/meditation_images/ocean.jpeg',
    ),
    Item(
      name: "Waterfall",
      audiopath: "assets/meditation_audios/waterfall.mp3",
      imagepath: 'assets/meditation_images/waterfall.jpeg',
    ),
    Item(
      name: "Wind",
      audiopath: "assets/meditation_audios/wind.mp3",
      imagepath: 'assets/meditation_images/wind.jpeg',
    ),
  ];


  final AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();


  int? playingIndex;
  Widget showIcon(int currentIndex) {
    if (playingIndex == currentIndex) {
      return const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.stop);
    } else {
      return const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.play);
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Center(
          child: Text("Meditation App"),
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    image: AssetImage(
                      items[index].imagepath,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                height: 100,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(items[index].name),
                  leading: IconButton(
                    icon: showIcon(index),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (playingIndex == index) {
                        setState(() {
                          playingIndex == null;
                        });
                        audioPlayer.stop();
                      } else {
                        try {
                          audioPlayer
                              .setAsset(items[index].audiopath)
                              .catchError((onError) {
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                              SnackBar(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5),
                                content: const Text("Error"),
                              ),
                            );
                          });
                          audioPlayer.play();
                          setState(() {
                            playingIndex == index;
                          });
                        } catch (error) {
                          print(error);
                        }
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

(The code is in Google docs)

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zyX2NwJInN8kl9ytyeBj7r828l5ifDlNA3p5ilQFlls/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Make bool variable for play/pause

```
var isPlaying = false;

onPressed: () {
   setState((){
   if(isPlaying) audioPlayer.stop();
   else audioPlayer.play();
   isPlaying = !isPlaying;
})
}
```